# Make the numbers 1-50 using the digits 2, 0, 2, 0

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers, calculation-puzzle

Try to make all the numbers from 1-50 using 2, 0, 2, 0 exactly once.

Rules:

1. Use only the operations +, -, *, /, !, exponents and square root
2. No rounding eg. `20 / (2+0!) = 6`
3. No adding extra numbers eg. `2 + 10 + 2 + 0 = 14`
4. Concatenation is allowed only in combining 2 and 0 to become 20
5. Try to get all in order (I bet you can’t)
6. Parentheses are also allowed
7. .2 is allowed

Comment: Please don't significantly change a question after answers have been given (and even accepted.)

Comment: I’m just expanding the question

Comment: Please don't. The Stack Exchange site format is "question-answer", and it doesn't really work for any other kind of interaction. For example "question-answer-modified question-new answer" will pretty much always change some good, honest, hard-working answers into "doesn't answer the question (anymore) and should be deleted" answers, which isn't fair for the answerers. If you think the expanded question is worth posting on its own, go ahead and post a new question instead.

Answer (score 4):

**All 1-50 solved.**

Solved but extending meanings of operators: $28, 34, 38, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 49, 50$

---

> $\frac{2}{0!}-2+0! = 1$
>  
>  $2+\frac{0}{2}+0 = 2$
>  
>  $2+\frac{0}{2}+0! = 3$
>  
>  $2+0+2+0 = 4$
>  
>  $2+0+2+0! = 5$
>  
>  $2+0!+2+0! = 6$
>  
>  $2^{0!+2} - 0! = 7$
>  
>  $2^{0!+2} - 0 = 8$
>  
>  $\frac{20}{2}-0! = 9$
>  
>  $\frac{20}{2}-0 = 10$
>  
>  $\frac{20}{2}+0! = 11$
>  
>  $2 \cdot (0!+2)! + 0 = 12$
>  
>  $2 \cdot (0!+2)! + 0! = 13$
>  
>  $20 - (2+0!)! = 14$
>  
>  $\frac{2+0!}{.2} + 0 = 15$
>  
>  $2^{0!+2+0!} = 16$
>  
>  $20 - (2+0!) = 17$
>  
>  $20 - 2 + 0 = 18$
>  
>  $20 - 2^0 = 19$
>  
>  $20 - (2 \cdot 0) = 20$
>  
>  $20 + 2 - 0! = 21$
>  
>  $20 + 2 - 0 = 22$
>  
>  $20 + 2 + 0! = 23$
>  
>  $(2+0+2+0)! = 24$
>  
>  $(2+0+2)! + 0! = 25$
>  
>  $20 + (2+0!)! = 26$
>  
>  $(2+0!)^{2+0!} = 27$
>  
>  $\text{square}(2) \cdot (0!+(2+0!)!) = 28$ (using `square`)
>  
> $\left \lfloor{\sqrt{20}}\right \rfloor! + \left \lfloor{\sqrt{20}}\right \rfloor = 28$ (using `floor`)
>  
> $((2+0!)!+2-0!)!!! = 28$ (using [Multifactorial](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Multifactorial.html), added by @Vepir)
>  
>  $\frac{(2+0!)!}{.2} - 0! = 29$
>  
>  $\frac{(2+0!)!}{.2} + 0 = 30$
>  
>  $\frac{(2+0!)!}{.2} + 0! = 31$
>  
>  $2^{(0!+2)!-0!} = 32$
>  
>  $\sqrt[.2]{0+2} + 0! = 33$
>  
>  $\sqrt[.2]{2} + 0! + 0! = 34$ (not in order)
>  
>  $2\cdot(-0!+((2+0!)!)!!!) = 34$ (using `unary minus` and [Multifactorial](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Multifactorial.html), added by @Vepir in comments)
>  
>  $(2+0!)!^2-0! = 35$
>  
>  $\left(2+0!\right)!\cdot \left(2+0!\right)! = 36$
>  
>  $((2+0!)!)^2+0! = 37$
>  
>  $(20-0!) \cdot 2 = 38$ (not in order, added by @UnidentifiedX)
>  $20 + ((2+0!)!)!!! = 38$ (using [Multifactorial](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Multifactorial.html))
>  
>  $2\cdot (-0!+20)$ (using `unary minus`, added by @Vepir in comments)
>  
>  $20\cdot 2-0! = 39$
>  
>  $20\cdot 2-0 = 40$
>  
>  $20\cdot 2+0! = 41$
>  
>  $2 \cdot (0!+20) = 42$ (added by @UnidentifiedX in comments)
>  
>  $!(2+0!+2)-0!=43$ (using [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement), added by @Vepir in comments)
>  
>  $!(2+0!+2)+0=44$ (using [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement), added by @Vepir in comments)
>  
>  $!(2+0!+2)+0!=45$ (using [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement), added by @Vepir in comments)
>  
>  $((2+0!)!)!! - 2 + 0 = 46$ (using [Multifactorial](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Multifactorial.html))
>  
>  $((2+0!)!)!! - !(2 + 0) = 47$ (using [Multifactorial](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Multifactorial.html) and [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement))
>  
>  $2\cdot(0!+2+0!)! = 48$
>  
>  $((2+0!)!+0!)^2 = 49$ (not in order, added by @JMP)
>  
>  $((2+0!)!)!! + !(2 + 0) = 49$ (using [Multifactorial](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Multifactorial.html) and [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement))
>  
>  $\frac{0!+0!}{.2^2} = 50$ (not in order, added by @JMP)
>  
>  $((2+0!)!)!! + 2 + 0 = 50$ (using [Multifactorial](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Multifactorial.html))

Comment: @Matheinstein Does `square()` count as an operation?

Comment: Square() involves the digit 2 so it doesn’t count as an operation

Comment: @Matheinstein If square root is fine, what about half root? Lol. I don't think 28 is possible without using either an extra square operation or half root.

Comment: Half root? I think that’s worse than the square since you add a 1 and a 2

Comment: By the way the question has changed

Comment: $49=((2+0!)!+0!)^2, 50=\frac{0!+0!}{.2^2}$, and, if you allow binomial, $28=\binom{-(2+0!)-0!}{2}$

Comment: So what is a .2 root

Comment: @eyl327 $35 = (2+0!)! - (2*0)!$

Comment: @eyl327 Is the solution for 49 supposed to have a factorial after $((2+0!)$

Comment: You can use "$!n$" in the context of [Derangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement)'s, where `!1=0,!2=1,!3=2,!4=9,!5=44,!6=265`,

$$
!(2+0!+2)-0!=43\\
!(2+0!+2)+0=44\\
!(2+0!+2)-0!=45\\
$$

Comment: For $28$, we can exploit another definition of "$!$". (see my comment on the other answer)

Comment: @Vepir Thanks for bringing those up! I have added yours and use those operations to add a few more.

Comment: @eyl327 Btw, $38=2\cdot (-0!+20)$ without multifactorial, and $34=2\cdot(-0!+((2+0!)!)!!!)$ in order using multifactorial.

Comment: @eyl327 38 can be expressed ad $(20-(0!))*2$

Comment: but not in order...

Comment: @eyl327 I cracked it... $42=2*(0!+20)$

Comment: Besides the "sguare" not being allowed, the floor function also is not allowed.

Answer (score 3):

Partial answer (all except 28, updated after .2 was allowed)

> $1=(2+0)/(2+0)$
>  $2=2+0\cdot2\cdot0$
>  $3=2+0\cdot2+0!$
>  $4=(2+0)\cdot(2+0)$
>  $5=(2+0)\cdot2+0!$
>  $6=(2+0!)!+2\cdot0$
>  $7=(2+0!)!+2-0!$
>  $8=(2+0!)!+2+0$
>  $9=(2+0!)!+2+0!$
>  $10=20/2+0$
>  $11=20/2+0!$
>  $12=(2+0!)!\cdot2+0$
>  $13=(2+0!)!\cdot2+0!$
>  $14=20-(2+0!)!$
>  $15=(2+0!)/.2+0$
>  $16=2^{0!+2+0!}$
>  $17=20-2-0!$
>  $18=20-2+0$
>  $19=20-2^0$
>  $20=20+2\cdot0$
>  $21=20+2^0$
>  $22=20+2+0$
>  $23=20+2+0!$
>  $24=(2+0+2)!+0$
>  $25=(2+0+2)!+0!$
>  $26=20+(2+0!)!$
>  $27=(2+0!)^{2+0!}$
>  $28=???$
>  $29=((2+0!)!)/.2-0!$
>  $30=((2+0!)!)/.2+0$

Comment: Your solution for 24 is incorrect... remove the last factorial?

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to remove it after copypasting.

Comment: If you allow "stacking" factorial into [Multifactorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Multifactorials), for example $7!!!=7\cdot4\cdot1=28$, then:

$$
28 = ((2+0!)!+2-0!)!!!
$$